# How to ls/cd using indexes rather than names

Tags: bash, shell, unix, ls, cd

So my normal way of moving around the file system is using `ls --color` to see all the files and directories and then typing in `cd [directory]` and then typing `ls --color` again and rinse and repeat until I find a file, where after I type `vim [file]` to edit it.

This is a pretty inefficient way to do things IMO. I was envisioning these features:

1. Combine `cd` and `ls --color` so that as soon as I `cd` into a directory it outputs the contents with color (so I can tell whats a directory and what's a file and etc)
2. Have `ls` and `cd` use indexes. What I mean is have the output of `ls` print numbers next to all the stuff in a directory like `[3]` for the 4th item or something so that all I have to do is type `cd [3]`. This would help because the file names are sometimes long (like really long) and contain spaces and I don't wanna retype the long command because of inevitable typos.

I'm not sure if something like this is already in bash, or if it's a plugin I can download or if I'll just need to write a shell script, but any help would be great!

**Edit:** I should add this for exploring the filesystem. I don't have a target file I'm trying to reach.

Comment: `find . -iname 'filetofind'` will probably help you search faster...

Comment: Thing is I don't know what I'm looking for I'm just poking around the filesystem

Comment: Maybe you'd enjoy using a visual file manager like midnight commander.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple ways to browse a filesystem that could be more efficient.

1. Use your shell's autocompletion feature. Probably the most efficient way to solve your problem.

   `cd /a/`<kbd>TAB</kbd><kbd>TAB</kbd>

   This will display the directories contained in `/a/` or, if there's only one (that corresponds to what you've typed so far) will autocomplete your command with it.
2. Use a GUI, as suggested in the comments.
3. Instead of alternatively using `ls` and `cd`, you could use multiple `ls` and a final `cd` :

   ```
   $ ls /a  
   > b/ c/ d/  
   $ ls /a/b  
   > e/  
   $ ls /a/b/e  
   >fileIWant  
   $ cd /a/b/e  
   $ vim fileIWant
   ```

   You can repeat the path of the last step using <kbd>ALT</kbd> +
   <kbd>.</kbd>.
   You don't even need the final `cd` and could directly use `vim /a/b/e/fileIWant`.
4. Use `ls` recursively : `ls -R /a`. The output can be a little hard to use.

Comment: `ls -R` crossed my mind earlier but then is there a way to use indexes with that? Cuz the paths might be _really_ nested in there

Comment: I wouldn't recommend a solution based on indexes because it will be a pain to use when directories contain 20+ subdirectories, which could happen quite often. Have you tried the autocompletion based solution? I really think this is what most people use.

Comment: I haven't really delved on how it's used because its quite intuitive, but what happens is that it will try to auto-complete your command line with something that makes sense (so, only directories when you're using `cd`, but also files if you're using another command like `vim`). If it fails to do so because there are multiple choices, it will display all the possible choices. When you use it just after having typed a directory, it will list the content of the directory. But if you've started typing a file or directory name,it will only show the files/directories that start by what you've typed

Comment: I guess there are the best ways to handle this. I just wanted to know if there was a way to match the speed of the visual file system and the mouse b/c the terminal is definitely faster at a lot of other things.

Comment: Well that's what I'm saying, use autocomplete. For example to reach my home, if it's `/home/Aaron`, I'll only type `/h<TAB>/A<TAB>`. That's supposing I'm the only user whose home directory starts by an "A". If there had been others, their directories and mine would have been displayed instead when pressing tabulation once again